# Grid with mouse focus

Tags: d3.js, zooming, scale, distortion

I am trying to prepare a grid with mouse zoom on it. What I mean is, when mouse is over a cell, cell will be magnified. But this effect will not break the grid structure.

Cells close to mouse cursor will be magnified. This effect will be reduced for the cells away from the mouse.

[image]

This is what i want to see. Any ideas how can I do this with d3js?

Comment: [Cartesian Distortion](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/#cartesian) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes yep, good one. but it has a bad feature which I dont like. When cursor is close to edges of the area, scaling is different from center. I want something like this: http://flare.prefuse.org/demo > scatter with distortion. but in this example only 2 cells around are scaled. but still better than cartesian.